# Do I need GPU drivers on Linux in VirtualBox

Tags: kali-linux, nvidia

I'm using a Linux distro on VirtualBox on my Windows 10 computer. 
I want to try a project on github and they recommend to install dependencies(drivers for GPU) for it to take advantage of the GPU. The project explains it using Ubuntu 16.04 and GeForce GTX 1060 on a machine.

```
sudo apt-get install -y nvidia-opencl-dev unzip libssl-dev mono-complete
```

Since Linux is running in a vm, I'm thinking it doesn't need external drivers. I'm hoping the VirtualBox GuestAdditions handles that part.

When issuing lspci -v i get this info on my "graphics card". It shows that the VirtualBox provides a kind of GPU bridge.

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH VirtualBox Graphics Adapter (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
Memory at e0000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=16M]
[virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
Kernel driver in use: vboxvideo
Kernel modules: vboxvideo
```

I'm using a GeForce 1070 GPU.

**Do I need to load external dependencies in order for programs to take advantage of my graphics card?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The virtualized video card provided by VirtualBox doesn't have any sort of GPU computation capabilities, or even any 3D acceleration.  It's essentially a simple VESA framebuffer.

There are two options for GPU acceleration of computations.  You can either run the program directly (non-virtualized), or you can use an emulator that supports PCI passthrough for video cards (the latter may also require that your CPU and mainboard support PCI virtualization).

Comment: Great! I'll try will try to use PCI passthrough on Virtualbox.